# How to make clear that a method can be overridden?

Tags: object-oriented, php

I have a library that I use in several applications. It has a method that returns a URL:

```
class UrlBuilder {
  public function url($config) {
    $config = do_some_checks($config);
    return make_url($config));
  }
}
```

Often an application wants to alter the way the URL is built, and I would like to make that clear from the way the library is implemented. I came up with these solutions:

1. Mention it in the library docs, but otherwise just let the application override the method like any other:

   ```
   class MyAppUrlBuilder extends UrlBuilder {
     public function url($config) {
       $config = do_some_checks($config);
       return make_url_differently($config);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Call a separate function that is just there to be overridden:

   ```
   class UrlBuilder {
     public function url($config) {
       $config = do_some_checks($config);
       $config = $this->alterConfig($config);
       return make_url($config));
     }

     protected function alterConfig($config) { return $config; }
   }
   ```
3. Provide a setter to set a customization callback:

   ```
   class UrlBuilder {
     public function url($config) {
       $config = do_some_checks($config);
       if ($this->configModifier)
         $config = $this->configModifier($config);
       return make_url($config));
     }

     public function setConfigModifier($configModifier) {
       $this->configModifier = $configModifier;
     }
   }
   ```

Is there a semantic difference and (if that is not a matter of taste) is any of them preferable?

Comment: For option 3, you could describe it as "provide a setter to provide customization instructions"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd prefer Option #4: Avoid relying on inheritance.

Just make `UrlBuilder` an *interface*, and give people some way to inject their own implementation to the process, overriding the default you provided.

```
interface UrlBuilder {
    public function url($config);
}

class DefaultUrlBuilder implements UrlBuilder{
  public function url($config) {
    $config = do_some_checks($config);
    return make_url($config));
  }
}
```

This way it shifts the responsibility: You don't *need* to worry too much about all the possible ways they might want to subclass your implementation, because they don't *have* to. If their needs are simple and they subclass it, well, good for them, they found a shortcut. If their needs are complex, well, they've got the freedom to do something else.

... That said, of the three options, my favorite is #2, if you have a very clear vision of exactly what they'll want to customize.